# Joint distributions

Tags: probability, joint-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variable with the following joint density function 
$$ f(x,y) = xy,\\ \text{for}\ 0\leq x \leq 2 \ \text{and} \ 0\leq y \leq 1$$

What is $P(X/2 \leq Y \leq X)$?

How do we put the limits of integral in this ?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read the tag wiki. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math.

Answer (score 1):

The region you'll integrate is between the lines $y=x/2, y=x$ and the rectangle $[0,2]\times[0,1]$. You need to draw this to see explicitly. The line $y=x/2$ passes through the upper-right corner of the rectangle and $y=x$ passes to the left of it. You can integrate this region first from $y$ then $x$ or vice versa, but the former is simpler in this figure. You'll have something like:

$$\int_0^1\int_{ay}^{by} f(x,y)dxdy$$

$a,b$ are for you to find. Draw the region described above, when $y$ is a fixed number, i.e. you move horizontally from left to right, where do you enter the region and where do you exit the region? Write those line equations as $x=ay, x=by$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? With this I get a triangle with top coordinates as (1,1). We enter the triangle at (1/2,1/2) and exit at (1,1/2). So which limits do we take ?

Comment: Why have you taken the outer limit as (0-1) , x tends from (0-2)

Comment: The outer integral is for $y$, note the order of the measures: $dxdy$. Try to enter the region with a fixed $y$ between $0$ and $1$. You can share the region plot you have to be more sure.\

Comment: So the limits of x is basically the points at which it cuts the line y=1? We write that as x=y and x=2y? As limits ?

Comment: If we reverse the order of integration , how do we apply the limits ? I mean first y and then x

Comment: Yes, limits are correct. But, they're not only for $y=1$, it's true for all $y$ between 0 and 1. Draw a horizontal line from an arbitrary y and mark the intersection points with the lines. Then, you'l see. If the order of integration is $dydx$, then you'll need to divide the integral into two parts. Try it and share your effort in the original question for review if you want, but it's easier this way.